# How to understand my network switch vLAN

Tags: networking, switch, documentation

I have a network switch that is unmanageable but it has (Vlan, Trunk, group, port and set) option via button. 
<del>I can't find a manual because there is no model or company name.</del>

Update: Appleoddity has identified this as an Edimax ES-3116RE+,
with [user manual here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/42796/Edimax-Es-3116rePlus.html). 
But I need help understanding how to configure vLANs.

---

The only thing  written on it is:

> Smart Switch   16-Port 10/100Mbps

and it has grey and white arrows on the front panel.

Front panel picture:
[image: Front panel]

Bottom panel picture:
[image: Bottom panel]

There is nothing else except that hole on the back. 
Back panel picture:
[image]
Detail:
[image]

Comment: Unmanaged switches are "dumb" switches and simply pass traffic but are unable to modify the traffic.  Without the model number _(should be on a label somewhere, perhaps on the back of bottom of the switch)_, or photo _(upload to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) then please post the share link in your question)_, it will be diffciult to provide correct advice

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NQ50S4b it's the grey one

Comment: Please add the link to your _question_, **not** as a comment

Comment: Please get the model number off the back or bottom of the switch

Comment: Okay thank you, i did not know as i am new of today. I've edited the post !

Comment: It’s an Edimax ES-3116RE+ - https://www.manualslib.com/manual/42796/Edimax-Es-3116rePlus.html

Comment: Thank you !! i've been looking for it for so long !!! may i ask how did you managed to find it ?

Answer (score 0):

The port-based VLANs that that switch supports partition your network into smaller networks (broadcast domains). Think of each VLAN as a separate switch.

> Virtual LAN (VLAN) is a logical subgroup within a local area network
>   which can be configure through port configuration. VLAN can be
>   configured to optimize traffic or to isolate specific workstations for
>   reasons of security or convenience. Each VLAN you configure behaves as
>   an isolated broadcast domain just as if it were a separate switch.
>   There is no communication between ports on the separate VLANs unless
>   the VLANs are connected by an external router.

— [Edimax ES-3116RE+ User Manual – Vlan Configuration
  – 6. Advance Configuration [Page 10]](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/42796/Edimax-Es-3116rePlus.html?page=10#manual)

Comment: ohh it's all clear now, i can't wait to test this on my homelab ! Thank you !!

Comment: Please don’t quote from a document without explicitly identifying the source: see [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing).